# Pull SecurityToken from SAML Assertion

Tags: c#, saml

I have the XML of a SAML Assertion that looks like this:

```
<saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_9b6e6302-d6a8-47f0-9155-1051a05edbfb" Issuer="http://example.com/adfs/services/trust" IssueInstant="2013-04-29T19:35:51.197Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
...
</saml:Assertion>
```

I am trying to get a SecurityToken out of this XML using code similar to the following:

```
// Loading the XML referenced above.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(assertion));

// Creating config to use in TokenHandlers below; required if not using a SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.
SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration config = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration();
config.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("https://localhost/Orchard/"));
config.CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None;

// Both of these lines throw Exceptions, as explained below.
new Saml11SecurityTokenHandler() { Configuration = config }.ReadToken(doc.CreateReader());
new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler() { Configuration = config }.ReadToken(doc.CreateReader());
```

If I try to read the token using the `Saml11SecurityTokenHandler`, I get the following Exception:

> ID4075: SAML Assertion is missing the required 'MajorVersion' Attribute.

If I try to read the token using the `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler`, I get a different Exception:

> Element 'Assertion' with namespace name 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion' was not found.

Obviously the one for `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler` makes sense, since this is a SAML 1.1 Assertion.  However, why can't the SAML 1.1 TokenHandler read this Assertion?

**EDIT**:  The reader appears to be empty; why is that?  `doc` has content.

```
string notEmpty = doc.FirstNode.ToString();
string empty = doc.CreateReader().ReadOuterXml();
```

Comment: Try to use XDocument.LoadXML instead

Comment: @Stefan:  The document has the data; it's either the reader or how the code was getting the data from the reader that doesn't.  However, I found an answer that works (below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drawing from the technique shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2012/11/02/saml-2-0-tokens-and-wif-bridging-the-divide.aspx), this works:

```
SecurityToken token;
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(assertion))
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    {
        if (!reader.ReadToFollowing("saml:Assertion"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Assertion not found!");
        }
        SecurityTokenHandlerCollection collection = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();
        token = collection.ReadToken(reader.ReadSubtree());
    }
}
```

Make sure you don't change of the whitespace in the XML document, otherwise you'll get a signature verification error.